# How does python debugger work?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a basic understanding of how a debugger work but that is in context of compiled languages. How does a debugger like `pdb` work?
At a very high level, I am looking for something that can explain internals of `pdb` or in general "debugging interpreted languages"

I googled up but couldn't get any doc.
This question might be too broad but link to some basic documents would allow me to study further.

Answer (score 2):

From [Python 2.7 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

> It supports setting (conditional) breakpoints and single stepping at
>   the source line level, inspection of stack frames, source code
>   listing, and evaluation of arbitrary Python code in the context of any
>   stack frame.

As mentioning above pdb provides you way of inspection stack frames(watching, listing, evaluation of code within frame).

Diving into frame objects would definitely help you in understanding pdb module. See [inspect — Inspect live objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) and [The interpreter stack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the "internals of pdb" part of the question